# Where are these allocations coming from and how does declaring the parameters' types prevent them?

Tags: optimization, julia, allocation

So I'm learning Julia by solving ProjectEuler problems and I came up with this code for [problem 27](https://projecteuler.net/problem=27):

```
function isPrime(num)
    num < 2 && return false
    for i in 2:trunc(Int, √num)
        if num % i == 0
            return false
        end
    end
    return true
end

function quadratic(n, a, b)
    return n^2 + a*n + b
end

function consecutivePrimes(a, b)
    count = 0
    tryNum = 0
    while true
        currResult = quadratic(tryNum, a, b)
        !isPrime(currResult) && (return count)
        count += 1
        tryNum += 1
    end
end

function longestConsecutivePrimes(modA, modB)
    longest = (0,0,0)
    for a in -modA:modA, b in -modB:modB
        consecutive = consecutivePrimes(a, b)
        longest[1] < consecutive && (longest = (consecutive, a, b))
    end
    return longest
end

A, B = 999, 1000
@time size, a, b = longestConsecutivePrimes(A, B)
println("size: $size, a: $a, b: $b")
println("a*b = $(a*b)")
```

Which yields

```
  0.106938 seconds (36.28 k allocations: 2.239 MiB, 38.39% compilation time)
size: 71, a: -61, b: 971
a*b = -59231
```

Now, by replacing the parameters in the function longestConsecutivePrimes for

```
function longestConsecutivePrimes(modA::Int64, modB::Int64)
```

The script, when run in a separate terminal independent from the one before, yields

```
  0.064875 seconds (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
size: 71, a: -61, b: 971
a*b = -59231
```

Which is double as fast and has just 1 allocation.

Each script run was made in the linux terminal, not in the Julia REPL, closing the terminal between each run, so one run doesn't "profit" from the other's compilations.

Where were the allocations coming from and how does declaring the parameters' types prevent them?

I feel like understanding this will help me improve previous and future Julia scripts I write.

Comment: Did you follow good practise on [proper benchmarking](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Measure-performance-with-[@time](@ref)-and-pay-attention-to-memory-allocation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, the allocations go away also when `A` and `B` stop being global variables, so it seems likely the difference is from type inference being more difficult (i.e. allocations from the type inference code itself).

> Is it considered bad practice to leave the end of my script as is, outside a function? Would it be more Julian to wrap it in a function that prints the result and the benchmarks?

Of particular importance here is to [avoid (non-`const`ant) global variables](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-global-variables). It's fine to have simple `print` statements (or `@benchmark` lines with `setup` code) in the global scope, but anything more  complicated will likely need non-constant variables and hence should be put into a function as the manual recommends. (Also see the "Annotate values taken from untyped locations" section in the same manual page, which is what your second script is doing.)

---

*Edit*: I'll leave this in in case it's useful to anyone else in the future, but this explanation doesn't apply in OP's case as mentioned in the comments.

The first time you `@time`d the function, since you were calling it with two `Int` arguments, Julia automatically compiled a specialized version of the function for `modA` and `modB` being `Int`s. The `@time` macro included the allocations and time taken for this compilation step also, in its result (as you can see from the "38.39% compilation time" part of the output).

When you changed the function to have type annotations and ran it again, Julia didn't have to compile anything because a compiled version of `longestConsecutivePrimes` that takes two `Int` arguments already existed. So in this run, only the execution of the function itself was timed, only its own allocations were reported.

So adding the type annotations didn't change the allocations or running time. However, what it did accomplish was adding a new "method" to the `longestConsecutivePrimes` function - one with more specialized arguments. So after this point, any calls to the function with purely `Int` argument would use your second definition, whereas calls with other types - `UInt8` or `Int128` or even `String` for eg. - would use your first definition of the function. It's effectively defined for `Any` type. In this case of course, both the defintions happen to be identical. But in general, this way of type-specializing functions is core to using Julia's multiple dispatch paradigm.

Comment: I responded to your comment in Oscar's answer and edited the question to make it more clear. The runs were not made in the REPL, but in the linux terminal, closing the terminal between each run.

Comment: Also, if I run the script with the types in the terminal first, and then run the version without the types in the same terminal without closing it, the yielded results are the same as shown in the question.

Comment: Ah, I think this case might be because `A` and `B` are global variables. I've experienced similar behaviour before. I'll update the answer in a bit.

Comment: Yes, it's an artifact of them being global variables, though I don't have the expertise to say exactly why it happens. If you put the last 4 lines in a `main` function and then call it in the last line of your script, there's suddenly no allocations, not even the one 16 byte allocation the type-annotated one here has.

Comment: The `@code_warntype` output is identical in all three cases. I guess it's the type inference working hard that leads to these allocations and compile time? Putting things in a function (localising the scope) or annotating them yourself makes its work much easier, so that makes sense as the source of difference.

Answer (score 1):

You were timing compilation. If you run the untyped function again, you'll see that it runs without extra allocation.

Comment: I would also mention `@benchmark` from BenchmarkTools.jl as that can help here a lot.

Comment: I know I'm timing compilation in both versions of the code. Still, when running the first version for the first time, it shows 36.28 k allocations when compiling. The second version (with type declaration), when running for the first time, has only one allocation. Both @time outputs were yielded from the 1st run of the function call from different scripts.

Comment: @MateusRodolfo But both were run from the same Julia REPL session, right? Also, see my answer for some more detail on what's happening.

Comment: @SundarR actually no. I'll edit the question to make it more clear. Both versions of the script were run in the linux terminal, closing the terminal between each script run.